# Post processing of data after inserting a row in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Below are my environment settings

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- ASP.NET MVC
- Entity Framework

In my application I want to do post processing of transaction after they are inserted in database. So basically I want a separate application to be listening to database events, and whenever a new row is created in table `Orders`, do some post processing (calling another webservice to process orders) on it.

I checked with EF and it seems it doesn't provide any such feature.

**Few other requirements**

- at this moment i am not looking for solution involving polling as it will increase db load.
- Want some kind of event to get triggered when a row is inserted.

What would be the best way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Create a T-SQL trigger on that table that inserts a small "command" entry into a separate "Command" table, with all the relevant information (e.g. `OrderId` and possibly others).

Then have your stand-alone application check that "Command" table on a regular basis (scheduled to check every 10 minutes - or whatever makes sense to you).

Based on the data read from the "Command" table, your application can then do any post-processing necessary, and update the underlying database table with the new information.

**Warning**: ***DO NOT*** put all this post-processing logic directly into the trigger! That would be a cardinal sin - a trigger should **never** do heavy and lengthy processing since that blocks the currently running transaction and kills your database's system performance *for sure*!

Comment: I do not want to do polling,i was looking more sort of event.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a Service bus, something like MassTransit.  Configure it to make use of it's Subscription service.

Once the order has been saved, raise an event on the bus, and have another service listen for this event.  Once the other service picks up the event, you can continue processing the order.

This is the MassTransit main page
http://masstransit-project.com/

And this is the configuration for the subscription service
http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/publishing.html

Comment: @AnshulNigam please see the added info in my answer

Comment: i read the document, and its more likely creating your own queue and then processing outside,sounds good will keep this in mind but currently looking for some internal event from sql server itself.

Comment: You can add a trigger to the table then but as mentioned it's not good for performance.  Why does it need to be in SQL

Comment: Yes, triggers are not good options as they are sync also, i need it to be in sql for two reasons 1. avoid any change in main application code 2. as we are already using SQL so my expectation is there should be something available already.

Comment: Perhaps SQL service broker could help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/07/09/real-time-data-integration-with-service-broker-and-other-sql-techniques.aspx